# Get the full Joomla URL for an image

Tags: php, flexicontent

Currently I am on my local server and the URL I want to create is:

http://localhost/cax2017/images/flexicontent/l_thecaxton.jpg

**/cax2017/images/flexicontent/l_thecaxton.jpg** is created by:

```
FlexicontentFields::getFieldDisplay($item, 'image', null, 'display_large_src', 'item');
```

If I use:

```
$url = JURI::base().FlexicontentFields::getFieldDisplay($item, 'image', null, 'display_large_src', 'item');
```

It fails as I get double **/cax2017/cax2017/**: http://localhost/cax2017/cax2017/images/flexicontent/l_thecaxton.jpg

I'm looking for a way to make it portable across hosts or servers.

I have solved it with this:

```
$siteURL='http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$url = $siteURL.FlexicontentFields::getFieldDisplay($item, 'image', null, 'display_large_src', 'item');

echo $url;
```

But is there a simpler Joomla way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it already does what you want.

Throughout code for Flexicontent, they generate links using `JURI::base(true)` and `JURI::root(true)`.  This is the same as `JURI::base()` and `JURI::root()`, but returns the absolute path only rather than the absolute link.

The double /cax2017/cax2017/ would certainly be consistant with this, so I assume the getFieldDisplay function works like this.

This approach means that you can move it to a different host without any issue - the links should update the path automatically when you set the new configuration file.

Comment: Thanks - however the full URL is required for google event schema to display image: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events

Comment: You sure? The URL schema that the image section of that page links to - http://schema.org/url gives an example of image with a relative path.

Comment: I've tried relative URL it fails: http://i.imgur.com/W3IaqCi.jpg
The google markup example is: 
"image": "http://www.example.com/event_image/12345",